# How to load image from relative url in addroid web view

Tags: android, android-webview, protocol-relative

I want to display image from relative url like (//via.placeholder.com/350x150) in android web view
Though i can see the html , but the image is broken in web view.

Below is my code to load image from custom html,  passed to webview.loadData function.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    String customHtml ="<html>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <h3>A demonstration of how to access an IMG element</h3>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <img id=\"myImg\" src=\"//via.placeholder.com/350x150\" alt=\"The Pulpit Rock\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\">\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <p>Click the button to get the URL of the image.</p>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <button onclick=\"myFunction()\">Try it</button>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <p id=\"demo\"></p>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    <script>\n" +
            "        function myFunction() {\n" +
            "        var x = document.getElementById(\"myImg\").src;\n" +
            "        document.getElementById(\"demo\").innerHTML = x;\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    </script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</body>";

   webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");       
}
```

i have proper permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>;
```

[image]

In my case, main problem is, i always get image with relative url i.e. it won't have http: or https: appended to the url.
So what setting or function i should use in android ,  to display images from relative url protocol.

Please help.

Comment: is it rendering properly in normal browser?

Comment: Yes. Its working fine in normal browser.

Comment: It seems you can't do that because you're getting your html from a string not an actual web page. The reason you are getting image in actual browser is because your can actually find the image file but your web view can't

Comment: It does not matter, whether html is being rendered through string or web page. If i prefix http: to  url //via.placeholder.com/350x150 then same html string display the image in webview. So issue is related to relative protocol. I am not sure,  how can i use relative protocol in web view and what android setting/persmission , i need to change.

Comment: You can prefix protocol type to image url if you want

Comment: This is what i mentioned in my question,  that i will  get image url dynamically with or without (http/https), and i will pass the same url to webview without any modification. In given code url is hard coded  and will be change dynamically., so i can't prefix protocol type.

Comment: if you're getting whole html code then it is difficult but if you're just getting img url you can easily prefix

Answer (score 0):

This issue is customHtml with wrong src.
Replace

`src=\"//via.placeholder.com/350x150\"`

by `src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"`.

Comment: I want to use relative instead absolute url. That why, i have omitted http in url. It seems  there is no way to do it in android web view.

Answer (score 0):

/index.html
/bin/image.png

```
<img src="/bin/image.png" /> will not currently work.
<img src="./bin/image.png" /> will work.
```